# Memory leak when displaying a modal view and dismissing it

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

When an AVExportSession is finished exporting, I have my app display a modal view displaying the video and an array of images. Dismissing the modal view, and making it display again over and over shows a memory increase that continuously grows. I'm suspicious of a strong reference cycle that could be occurring.

I'm setting required variables on the modal view (manageCaptureVC). fileURL is a global variable that manageCaptureVC can read from to get the video. The video is removed based on that URL when the modal view is dismissed. The leak is larger depending on the size of the media that is captured and displayed in the modal view.

I have used the Leaks Instrument. Unfortunately, it never points to any of my functions. It shows memory addresses that displays assembly language. I am also using a device.

Here is a screen shot of my leaks instrument at the point I display and dismiss my view, and the instrument indicates leaks:

[image]

Anything obvious what could cause a leak in my case?

Presenting the modal view (manageCaptureVC)

```
// video done exporting

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
exporter.outputURL = mainVideoURL
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

let manageCaptureVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManageCaptureVC") as! ManageCaptureVC

exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {[weak self]
() -> Void in

    let fileManagement = FileManagement()
    fileManagement.checkForAndDeleteExportFile() // delete export file


    self?.myTimer.invalidate()

    fileURL = mainVideoURL

    guard let imgCaptureModeRawVal = self?.imageCaptureMode.rawValue else { return }

    manageCaptureVC.imageCaptureMode = ManageCaptureVC.imageCaptureModes(rawValue: imgCaptureModeRawVal)!

    manageCaptureVC.delegate = self


    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
        manageCaptureVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self?.present(manageCaptureVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

})
```

Dismissing the view:

```
func goBackTask(){

    // turn off manage capture tutorial if needed
    if debug_ManageCaptureTutorialModeOn {
        debug_ManageCaptureTutorialModeOn = false
        delegate?.resetFiltersToPrime()
    }
    // no longer ignore interface orientation
    ignoreSelectedInterfaceOrientation = false

    // remove observer for the application becoming active in this view
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                              name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                              object: nil)

    if let videoEndedObs = self.videoEndedObserver {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(videoEndedObs)
    }

    // invalidate thumb timer
    thumbColorTimer.invalidate()

    // empty UIImages
    uiImages.removeAll()

    // delete video
    let fileManagement = FileManagement()
    fileManagement.checkForAndDeleteFile()

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.enableButtons(enabled:false)
        if let p = self.player, let pl = self.playerLayer {
            p.pause()
            pl.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "videoRect")
            pl.removeFromSuperlayer()
            p.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        }

        group.leave()
    }

    let group2 = DispatchGroup()

    group.notify(queue: .main) {

        group2.enter()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.enableButtons(enabled:true)
            group2.leave()
        }

    }

    group2.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: There's really no need to ask humans to review your code. If there's a leak, Instruments will tell you what it is and show you the retains that cause it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that memory management on a Simulator in Debug mode is no indication of what will happen on a device in Release mode.

Comment: I have used the Leaks Instrument. Unfortunately, it never points to any of my functions. It shows memory addresses that displays assembly language. I am also using a device.

Comment: Use the Allocations instrument with retain tracking to see what's leaking and why.

Comment: I have. It doesn't show anything helpful. I can update the post with screenshots of the leaks or allocations instrument.

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshot

Comment: Any function I click on the right pane for any leak, it just shows assembly language. Is that normal? I tried it for every single leak.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well. It took me days to track it down.
Setting modalPresentationStyle to .fullScreen resulted in the View Controller not being released. I was able to reproduce this on a trivially simple example.
I got round it by setting modalPresentationStyle to .currentContext.
None of the Instruments identified this retain cycle - I guess because it was in low level Apple code.